# Pass fields with POST curl

Tags: php, curl

I have something working fine in Postman. Using POST, two headers (Accept and Content-Type, both application/json), and with the body having this JSON:

```
{
  "conditions": {
    "type": "0",
    "flag": "0"
  }
}
```

I'm trying to mimic this with a PHP curl.. but I keep getting a null result. This is my effort so far, based on things I've seen various places.

```
$path = "same/path/as/postman";
$data = array("conditions" => array("type" => 0, "flag" => 0));
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query( $data ) );
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array( 'Accept: application/json', 'Content-Type: application/json'));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $path);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$result = curl_exec($curl);
print("<div>RESULT:</div><pre>");
print_r($result); // null
print("</pre>");
```

Comment: You should use `json_encode` to serialize the array instead of `http_build_query`

Comment: That seems to have fixed things, thanks. @FrederickZhang

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a curl class written by myself. I've been using it for a long time. Hope this helps.

```
class httpReq
{
    public static $unique = null;

    public static function httpGet($url, $params = null, $header = null, $cacheCookie = false)
    {
        if (!isset(self::$unique)) {
            self::$unique = uniqid();
        }

        if ($params != null && count($params) > 0) {
            $url = httpReq::getUrlBuilder($url, $params);
        }

        $ch = curl_init();

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
        if ($cacheCookie) {
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, sprintf('/tmp/cookie_%s.txt', self::$unique));
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, sprintf('/tmp/cookie_%s.txt', self::$unique));
        }
        if ($header != null) {
            if (is_array($header)) {
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
            } else {
                $request_headers = array();
                $request_headers[] = $header;
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $request_headers);
            }
        }

        $output = curl_exec($ch);

        curl_close($ch);
        return $output;
    }

    public static function httpPost($url, $params, $header = null, $arrayJsonEncoded = true, $cacheCookie = false)
    {
        if (!isset(self::$unique)) {
            self::$unique = uniqid();
        }

        if (is_array($params)) {
            // Post an array, only values will be url encoded
            // JSON Encoding is only available in this mode

            $postData = '';
            if ($arrayJsonEncoded) {
                $postData = json_encode($params);
                if ($header == null) {
                    $header = array();
                }
                $header[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
            } else {
                //create name value pairs separated by & and url encode the values
                foreach ($params as $k => $v) {
                    $postData .= $k . '=' . urlencode($v) . '&';
                }
                rtrim($postData, '&');
            }

            $ch = curl_init();

            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
            if ($cacheCookie) {
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, sprintf('/tmp/cookie_%s.txt', self::$unique));
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, sprintf('/tmp/cookie_%s.txt', self::$unique));
            }
            if ($header != null) {
                if (is_array($header)) {
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
                } else {
                    $request_headers = array();
                    $request_headers[] = $header;
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $request_headers);
                }
            }

            $output = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);
            return $output;
        } else {
            // Post a raw datum

            $ch = curl_init();

            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
            if ($cacheCookie) {
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, sprintf('/tmp/cookie_%s.txt', self::$unique));
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, sprintf('/tmp/cookie_%s.txt', self::$unique));
            }
            if ($header != null) {
                if (is_array($header)) {
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
                } else {
                    $request_headers = array();
                    $request_headers[] = $header;
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $request_headers);
                }
            }

            $output = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);
            return $output;
        }
    }

    private static function getUrlBuilder($baseUrl, $params)
    {
        $url = $baseUrl;
        if ($url[strlen($url - 1)] != '?') {
            $url .= '?';
        }
        $url .= http_build_query($params);
        return substr($url, 0, strlen($url) - 1);
    }
}
```